# /dev/ipmi0 does not exist R710 SLES 11 SP2

Tags: linux, dell, ipmi, sles11, dell-openmanage

I have been searching without success to find how to get `ipmitool` to work. It is dependent on `/dev/ipmi0` existing, however in my case it doesn't. Here's some information that I think would be helpful:

```
# service ipmi status
ipmi_msghandler module loaded.
ipmi_si module loaded.
ipmi_devintf module loaded.
/dev/ipmi0 does not exist.

# ./srvadmin-services.sh status
dell_rbu (module) is running
ipmi driver is stopped
dsm_sa_datamgrd (pid 30636) is running
dsm_sa_eventmgrd (pid 30757) is running
dsm_sa_snmpd (pid 30816) is running
dsm_om_shrsvcd (pid 30894) is running
dsm_om_connsvcd (pid 30919 30918) is running

ipmi message handler version 39.2
May 29 13:36:13 # kernel: [11369545.480521] IPMI System Interface driver.
May 29 13:36:13 # kernel: [11369545.480523] ipmi_si: probing via hardcoded address
May 29 13:36:13 # kernel: [11369545.480524] ipmi_si: Adding hardcoded-specified kcs state machine
May 29 13:36:13 # kernel: [11369545.480526] ipmi_si: Trying hardcoded-specified kcs state machine at i/o address 0xca2, slave address 0x0, irq 0
May 29 13:36:13 # kernel: [11369545.480532] ipmi_si: Interface detection failed

   # service ipmi restart
Stopping all ipmi     drivers:                                                                        done
Starting ipmi drivers:                                                                            done

# zypper se ipmi
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...


S | Name             | Summary                           | Type     
--+------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------
i | OpenIPMI         | OpenIPMI                          | package  
  | OpenIPMI-devel   | OpenIPMI  - Development libraries | package  
i | ipmitool         | Utility for IPMI Control          | package  
  | ipmitool         | Utility for IPMI Control          | srcpackage
  | libipmi0         | IPMI library for iDRAC update     | package  
i | slessp1-ipmitool | Recommended update for ipmitool   | patch    
i | slessp2-ipmitool | Recommended update for ipmitool   | patch


# rpm -qa | grep srvadmin
    srvadmin-sysfsutils-7.2.0-4.1.595.sles11
    srvadmin-omacs-7.2.0-4.459.9.sles11
    srvadmin-deng-snmp-7.2.0-4.183.49.sles11
    srvadmin-tomcat-7.2.0-4.459.11.sles11
    srvadmin-webserver-7.2.0-4.9.3.sles11
    srvadmin-racadm4-7.2.0-4.25.868.sles11
    srvadmin-itunnelprovider-7.2.0-4.468.10.sles11
    srvadmin-racadm5-7.2.0-4.3.567.sles11
    srvadmin-racdrsc-7.2.0-4.481.10.sles11
    srvadmin-rac4-7.2.0-4.25.868.sles11
    srvadmin-server-cli-7.2.0-4.9.3.sles11
    srvadmin-idrac-vmcli-7.2.0-4.40.6.sles11
    srvadmin-hapi-7.2.0-4.237.42.sles11
    srvadmin-omilcore-7.2.0-4.822.1.sles11
    srvadmin-deng-7.2.0-4.183.49.sles11
    srvadmin-idracadm-7.2.0-4.481.10.sles11
    srvadmin-rac-components-7.2.0-4.481.10.sles11
    srvadmin-omcommon-7.2.0-4.459.9.sles11
    srvadmin-isvc-snmp-7.2.0-4.325.23.sles11
    srvadmin-idrac-7.2.0-4.481.10.sles11
    srvadmin-base-7.2.0-4.9.3.sles11
    srvadmin-server-snmp-7.2.0-4.9.3.sles11
    srvadmin-storageservices-7.2.0-4.9.3.sles11
    srvadmin-storelib-sysfs-7.2.0-4.1.594.sles11
    srvadmin-realssd-7.2.0-4.531.5.sles11
    srvadmin-argtable2-7.2.0-4.2.598.sles11
    srvadmin-idrac-ivmcli-7.2.0-4.2.7.sles11
    srvadmin-oslog-7.2.0-4.822.1.sles11
    srvadmin-standardAgent-7.2.0-4.9.3.sles11
    srvadmin-rac4-populator-7.2.0-4.25.868.sles11
    srvadmin-ominst-7.2.0-4.459.11.sles11
    srvadmin-smweb-7.2.0-4.528.5.sles11
    srvadmin-omacore-7.2.0-4.459.11.sles11
    srvadmin-storage-cli-7.2.0-4.528.5.sles11
    srvadmin-storageservices-cli-7.2.0-4.9.3.sles11
    srvadmin-xmlsup-7.2.0-4.458.9.sles11
    srvadmin-storelib-7.2.0-4.525.5.sles11
    srvadmin-racsvc-7.2.0-4.25.868.sles11
    srvadmin-idrac-snmp-7.2.0-4.481.10.sles11
    srvadmin-rac5-7.2.0-4.3.567.sles11
    srvadmin-storageservices-snmp-7.2.0-4.9.3.sles11
    srvadmin-smcommon-7.2.0-4.528.5.sles11
    srvadmin-jre-7.2.0-4.460.9.sles11
    srvadmin-isvc-7.2.0-4.325.23.sles11
    srvadmin-storage-7.2.0-4.528.5.sles11
    srvadmin-storage-snmp-7.2.0-4.528.5.sles11
    srvadmin-all-7.2.0-4.9.3.sles11


# lsmod | grep ipmi
ipmi_devintf           17509  0
ipmi_si                53294  0
ipmi_msghandler        49895  2 ipmi_devintf,ipmi_si
```

Why doesn't `/dev/ipmi0` exist and how can I make it exist?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a hardware problem with your BMC. Does it show up in `dmidecode`'s output? You should see something matching "ipmi" or "kcs" or "BMC".

Comment: After executing the command and finding the patter of ipmi, kcs, or BMC, I'm unable to reveal anything with that pattern.

Comment: Got it rmmod ipmi_si && modprobe -v ipmi_si type="kcs" ports="0xca8" regspacings="4"